# PHP mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm coding a CMS system to my friend  and everything has going fine until  yesterday, so updating query don't work somehow, I have double checked the queries and cannot find an error.  Everything else working just fine maybe I have done a little mistake what I cannot see , if you guys could help me out a little bit I would appreciate it ..

here is my sql query

```
$query = "UPDATE posts2  SET";
$query .= "post_title = '{$post_title}', ";
$query .= "post_category_id = '{$post_category_id}', ";
$query .= "post_date =  now(), ";
$query .= "post_author = '{$post_author}', ";
$query .= "post_status = '{$post_status}', ";
$query .= "post_tags = '{$post_tags}', ";
$query .= "post_content = '{$post_content}', ";
$query .= "post_image = '{$post_image}' ";
$query .= "WHERE id = {$the_post_id} " ;
```

Comment: sql injection everywhere! , but I'll just assume they where escaped off the question.

Comment: Your code is subject to SQL Injection. Please checkout mysqli or PDO and prepared statements. What error are you getting?

Comment: This is why you should just use a single string, and not concat it. Its easy to forget a space somewhere, like you did, after `SET`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Try echo'ing out the query, inspect it and run it in another tool like phpmyadmin against the database directly. This will likely make the error more obvious.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Well yeah, I'm using "mysqli", but before I move this to production server I'm gonna double check all the security issues , so it is not my main problem right now, but I got it work, so I forgotten lest space after SET so that I did not noticed ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try code given below

```
$query = "UPDATE posts2 SET ";
$query .= "post_title = '{$post_title}', ";
$query .= "post_category_id = '{$post_category_id}', ";
$query .= "post_date =  now(), ";
$query .= "post_author = '{$post_author}', ";
$query .= "post_status = '{$post_status}', ";
$query .= "post_tags = '{$post_tags}', ";
$query .= "post_content = '{$post_content}', ";
$query .= "post_image = '{$post_image}' ";
$query .= "WHERE id = {$the_post_id} " ;
```

you left no space after SET on the first line of your query. Also please check you're inserting category id as varchar. If it's numeric field please remove quotes around it.

Comment: No it is working thanks a lot , I didn't notice that I've forgotten that space after SET , even how many hours I read through the code , now it is working ..

Comment: You're welcome! If your issue is resolved mark it as resolved!